# Dart Fails to save Bytes to PNG, JPEG

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have been trying for hours to figure out why my code is not working. Basically, I have an image. I load its bytes into dart as a list of Uint8List. Then, I replace the values of the list with some other values. The problem is that after replacing the values, when I call the File().writeAsBytes() function, **the image is CORRUPTED.** Don't know why this is happening. Tried doing everything I could.

---

```dart
var b = File("assets/1K91k (1).jpg").readAsBytesSync();
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    double check = b[i] / 255;
    if (check > 0.8) {
      b[i] = 255;
    } else {
      b[i] = 2;
    }
  }
  File("/home/kq1231/Desktop/test.jpg")
    ..createSync()
    ..writeAsBytesSync(b);
}
```

I tried converting the **b** list to a Uint8List but to no avail.

Comment: "Then, I replace the values of the list with some other values." *You* are corrupting your image.  You can't arbitrarily replace bytes in a *compressed/encoded* image. If you don't do that and just write the original bytes, you'll see that Dart is not at fault.

Comment: Yeah. But I need to apply some operation on an image. I want to color the pixels based on certain threshold. But how do I save the bytes? Can you please help?

Comment: You must *decode* the image first to uncompressed pixel data first, manipulate the pixel data, and then re-encode the image to PNG or to JPEG. [`package:image`](https://pub.dev/packages/image) would help.

Comment: I am trying to use the image package but cannot understand how to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels funny to answer my own question but here's how it got working:

```dart
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image;
import 'dart:io';

image.Image prettify(String fileName, String exportPath, String imageName,
    double threshold, int blurRadius) {
  var b = image.decodeImage(File(fileName).readAsBytesSync());
  b = image.gaussianBlur(b!, blurRadius);
  for (int i = 0; i < b.width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b.height; j++) {
      var pix = b.getPixel(i, j);
      if ((image.getBlue(pix) + image.getRed(pix) + image.getGreen(pix)) /
              (255 * 3) >
          threshold) {
        b.setPixel(i, j, 0xffffff);
      } else {
        b.setPixel(i, j, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  File("$exportPath/$imageName")
    ..createSync()
    ..writeAsBytesSync(image.encodePng(b));
  return b;
}
```

This is a function called prettify. It applies a specific operation to a given image. First, decode the image. Then, loop through each pixel, average the R, G and B values to get the grayscale value (get the value of the pixel using **image.getPixel()** and set its value using **image.setPixel()**). Then, encode it back to .png format and save it.

**Note that *image* is the name of the library imported.**